# Is it necessary to have SL4A pre-installed on the android device to run apps developed in python?

Tags: android, python, sl4a

I understand that we need to install in the device we test, Once we start distributing the app, Is it necessary that the clients' Android device has SL4A previously installed or can we pack it with the application?

Answer (score 2):

You can create an APK with an embedded interpreter, so there is no need for SL4A installed.

Instructions are [here](http://code.google.com/p/android-python27/).

Comment: I checked it I think You need to read a bit more on that, I didnt see a single line saying that you wont require SL4A

Comment: In the contrary, I don't see a single line that you need SL4A. The [download description](http://code.google.com/p/android-python27/downloads/detail?name=PythonAPK.apk&can=2&q=) makes it very clear.